# How do the spin-matrices change in systems without spherical symmetry?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecular-orbital-theory, electrons, electronic-configuration

The (non-relativistic) spin matrices of a free electron, with $z$ as the quantization axis, read:
$$
\boldsymbol{S}_{x}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right], \quad \boldsymbol{S}_{y}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{array}\right], \quad \boldsymbol{S}_{z}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right].
$$
The eigenvalues of these matrices are related to the energies when measuring the particle in a particular spin state. The spherical symmetry is reflected in $\boldsymbol{S}_x$ and $\boldsymbol{S}_y$ which have the same energy eigenvalues. My question now is, what happens if we consider a doublet molecule *without* symmetry along the $x$- and $y$-directions? Will $\boldsymbol{S}_x$ and $\boldsymbol{S}_y$ then no longer have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: Why should the operators be different when the system is changed? You can talk about the (linear) momentum of an electron or a neutron or a molecule or a cow, but in all cases, we still have $p_x = -\mathrm{i}\hbar(\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x)$. Surely, the *expectation values* $\langle \psi | \hat{O} | \psi \rangle$ may be different, but that's no reason to change the underlying matrices $\hat{O}$ themselves; in fact the Pauli matrices are sacrosanct because they must obey the laws of angular momentum, namely, the commutation relation $[S_i, S_j] = \mathrm{i}\hbar \sum_k \varepsilon_{ijk}S_k$.

Comment: Also, this was crossposted from Physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/706299/how-do-the-spin-matrices-change-in-systems-without-spherical-symmetry

Comment: @orthocresol. I realize now that it was a stupid question. The operators stay the same, but the eigenvalues (and expectation values) change because the wave function changes. Thank you.

Comment: No, the eigenvalues don't change; the eigenvalues are only dependent on the operator, and they are still $\pm 1/2$! But the expectation values will change depending on the system under consideration. Not a stupid question, btw.

Comment: What I don't get is that if the matrices don't change, and the eigenvalues don't change, how can the expectation values change? If we have $\langle\psi|\hat{O}_1|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|E_1|\psi\rangle=E_1\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=E_1$ for a free particle, and the operators and eigenvalues stay the same, then we should get $\langle\psi|\hat{O}_2|\psi\rangle=E_2=E_1$. I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: I know that the wave function should change, but the wave-vectors must still be a linear combination of the same two eigenvectors.

Comment: Well, it's a linear combination, but the coefficients can vary: if you have $|\psi\rangle = c_\alpha |\alpha\rangle + c_\beta|\beta\rangle$ then the expectation value $\langle \psi | S_z | \psi \rangle = \hbar(|c_\alpha|^2 - |c_\beta|^2)/2$, and obviously this value depends on what $c_\alpha$ and $c_\beta$ are and thus what the state $\psi$ is. The same generally holds true of $S_x$ and $S_y$ but the maths is uglier. I'm not sure how you obtained the first equality in your comment; that only holds true if $\psi$ is an eigenstate of the operator with eigenvalue $E_1$, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, it was assumed that $\psi$ was one of the two eigenvectors. And yes, I get it now that the difference in the expectation values comes down to the difference in the weights of the eigenvectors. Thank you for the clarification.